# Push View In table view ?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

In My Application I Build Every Thing Dynamic And I Doesn't Use Storyboard .
I Cannot push view controller when i pressed in cell 
This is My Code .

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TripDetailView * TripDetailViewObjec = [[TripDetailView alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:TripDetailViewObjec animated:YES];
}
```

what i can do in this problem?
thanks in advance

Comment: cross check whether you added delegate in XIB or by code

Comment: First of all, please clarify whether `TripDetailView` is UIView or UIViewController subclass, the latter must be implemented to be used with the navigationController. Secondly, please confirm `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called and do check `self.navigationController` is not nil (it is nil if `self` - as UIViewController instance - is not in the navigationController stack).

Comment: TripDetailView  : is UIViewController. 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath : is Called .
how can i check self.navigationController is not nil ?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);

Comment: Thanks trapper
self.NavigationController = null .....
what can i do ?

Comment: Did you create a navigation controller at all? Please show the related code.

Answer (score 0):

In Your App Delegate, first create a navigation controller and push your table view controller on it like this

```
UITableViewController *tvc = [[UITableViewController alloc] init]; // your tableViewController
UINavigationController *nav = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tvc];
[tvc release];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[nav release];
```

than your navigation controller wont be null and you can push new View Controller on It, like this!

```
TripDetailView * TripDetailViewObjec = [[TripDetailView alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:TripDetailViewObjec animated:YES];
```

Comment: how i  addSubView:nav   and nav is not view

Comment: and still Self.Navigation=null

Comment: @TefaMohamed yes my bad! You had to set it to rootViewController, i have edited the post, have a look again... and by the way the if you go to your app delegate file -> applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: You would see this line too just change them this way!